# Running async methods from contructor or propertys

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm

I am using MVVM and WPF, now I am calling async process from my viewmodel class's constructor like this:
 `Task.Run(() => this.MyMetho(someParam)).Wait();` 
The problem with this is that screen freeze it until the task ends.

Another way is to create a `LoadDataMethod` in the ViewModel and call it from the view  in the event handler for `UserControl_Loaded` something like this

```
private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VMRep vm = (VMRep)this.DataContext;
    await vm.LoadDataMethod();
}
```

that way works better, but I guess there is a better way to do the load of async data for a View.

Thanks for your comments

Comment: Unfortunately, c# doesnt support Async Contructors. Neither does it support Async Properties. Your approach is fine as it is

Comment: Yes there is nothing to be done about it. In general I use constructs like `var runAndForget = MethidAsync();` in constructors just to be explicit about it.

Comment: You could also use [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx). Fill the lazy in your constructor into a private field with the specific methods and call them whenever you want.

Comment: I did not know about Lazy  I gonna read about it, Do you have any sample code or link with samples?
Until now it look like the best approach to avoid freeze the view is load the data on the `UserControl_Loaded`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish I'm trying my best to give you a brief explanation about [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

```
   private Lazy<Task<string>> getInfo;
```

In this case I'm holding a field with `Lazy<Task<string>>` in your case it would be `Lazy<Task<VMRep>>`. I'm using this field, so that you can call this lazy initialzier inside your class.

---

```
   public Laziness()
   {
     this.getInfo = new Lazy<Task<string>>(async () => await this.GetInfo());
   }
```

In the constructor I'm assigning the value to the lazy field. In this case with the method `GetInfo()`

---

```
   public string GetLazyInfo
   {
     get
     {
        return this.getInfo.Value.Result;
     }
   }
```

Exposing the `getInfo` field with a public property. And returning the result from the task inside the lazy.

---

```
   private async Task<string> GetInfo()
   {
     await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000));
     return await Task.Run(() => "test");
   }
```

And finally the method, where your magic can happen.

Comment: thanks this  is a really really new approach for me, I going to read more about it.
Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can create async factory method, and make your constructor private or protected

```
public static async bool Create() {
    var control = new UserControl();
    return await LoadDataMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I guess there is a better way to do the load of async data for a View

The key is to realize that all ViewModels must initialize *immediately*. If you think about it, it doesn't make sense to initialize them *asynchronously*, because when WPF constructs your VM, it has to show it right away. Not 10 seconds from now whenever the download completes.

So, shift your thinking a bit, and the answer will become clearer. Your VM needs to initialize immediately, but you don't have the data to display yet. So the appropriate thing to do is to immediately initialize to a kind of "loading..." state and *start* the download of the data. When the data arrives, then you *update* the VM to show the data.

You *can* do it the way you have it:

```
private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  VMRep vm = (VMRep)this.DataContext;
  await vm.LoadDataMethod();
}
```

but this doesn't provide a clean way for your View to detect whether the data is loading or has completed loading. I wrote a [data-bindable `Task<T>` wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (updated version [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs)) that helps with this kind of situation. It can be used like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
  MyData = NotifyTask.Create(LoadDataAsync());
}

public NotifyTask<TMyData> MyData { get; }
```

and then your View can data-bind to `MyData.Result` to get to the data, as well as other properties such as `MyData.IsNotCompleted` to show/hide "loading" indicators.