# Run the application faster with Run Query at Start

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, async-await

When the application runs, multiple queries run.

Now, since the amount of information has increased (500 KB SQLite database size), the program runs with a delay of 5 seconds. What should I do to run the app faster?

This is the code I have written:

```
public void getInitialData()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DataClass.myDbContext())
        {
            var query = db.Schools.ToList();
            txtScCount.Text = query.Count().ToString();
            var query2 = db.Users.ToList();
            txtUCount.Text = query2.Count().ToString();
            var query3 = db.Students.ToList();
            txtStCount.Text = query3.Count().ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

private void getSchool()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DataClass.myDbContext())
        {
            var query = db.Schools.Select(x => x);
            if (query.Any())
            {
                cmbEditBase.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getInitialData();
    getSchool();
    cmbEditBase.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(FindElement.Settings.DefaultSchool);
    getTopStudent(Convert.ToInt64(cmbEditBase.SelectedValue));

    try
    {
        using (var db = new DataClass.myDbContext())
        {
            long baseId = Convert.ToInt64(cmbEditBase.SelectedValue);
            var query = db.Scores.Join(
               db.Students,
               c => c.StudentId,
               v => v.Id,
               (c, v) => new DataClass.DataTransferObjects.StudentsScoresDto { Id = c.Id, BaseId = v.BaseId, StudentId = v.Id, Name = v.Name, LName = v.LName, FName = v.FName, Scores = c.Scores }
           ).Where(y => y.BaseId == baseId).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could/should populate your model asynchronously, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076147/running-async-methods-from-contructor-or-propertys

Comment: 500KB is **nothing** to even the slowest of computers nowadays, or to SQLite. The db could fit easily into memory entirely, and it's quite fast to load it to your program. It's unlikely that the delay comes from the DB at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load *the entire table* into memory:

```
var query = db.Schools.ToList();
txtScCount.Text = query.Count().ToString();
```

If all you need is the record count, then just get the record count:

```
txtScCount.Text = db.Schools.Count().ToString();
```

Let Entity Framework help you optimize your data queries against the database engine.  Database engines are *really good* at optimizing query execution paths.  Don't just load your entire database into in-memory arrays and try to optimize yourself.

Aside from that, the code you're showing really doesn't have any heavy operations.  Make sure you confirm specifically what/where your actual bottleneck is.  I'd hesitate to assume it's from a measly 500KB of data.  On the scale of large amounts of data, 500KB of data is indistinguishable from no data.

---

Side note: You *probably* shouldn't do this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

What this tells the code is "if there ever any error at all, I don't want to know about it."  So if you ever find yourself trying to chase down a bug or strange error, just remember that you specifically told the code not to tell you if anything goes wrong :)

At the very least, capture the exception into a variable and log it somewhere.  Or don't catch the exception at all and let it bubble up the stack to something else that can meaningfully catch and handle it.